# Algebraic characterization (or sufficient condition) when a (graded) local hypersurface has rational singularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, birational-geometry, hilbert-polynomial, gorenstein

Let $(S, \mathfrak n)$ be a regular local ring of dimension $d\ge 4$ and let $R=S/(f)$ , where $0\ne f \in \mathfrak n^2$. Then $\dim R=d-1\ge 3$. If $\mathfrak m$ is the maximal ideal of $R$ then $\mu (\mathfrak m)=\mu (\mathfrak n)=d=\dim R+1$. Let $\operatorname {ord}(f):=\max \{t : f\in \mathfrak n^t\}$. Then the Hilbert-Samuel multiplicity (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Samuel_function) of $R$ can be calculated as $e(R)=\operatorname {ord}(f)$.

Now my question is: Is there any Algebraic characterization (possibly in terms of $e(R)$) of when $R$ has at worst Rational singularity (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_singularity) ?

(If needed, I'm willing to assume $R$ is complete and normal and contains an algebraically closed field)

(If anything is known if we replace the regular local ring $S$ by a polynomial ring over a field , I'd appreciate even that)

Thanks

Comment: $e(R)$ or $\ord(f)$ is too weak for such characterizations. For example, if $e(R)=2$, then we should have a rational double point (say when $\dim R=2$). But, these are very special among all double points.

Comment: @Mohan: I meant to say some characterization involving $e(R)$ but not only $e(R)$ ... one of-course possibly have to use some other invariants or conditions too ...

Comment: @Mohan: for example: does rational singularity imply (or is implied by) the condition : $e(R)/2\le (\dim R -1)!$ ? (Through-out I'm assuming $R$ is a nice enough (with normal, complete, Algebraic closed residue field etc.)  hypersurface  )

Comment: Also, I'm really interested in dimension at least $3$ so I edited the question suitably taking care of that ...

Comment: In the graded case, there is a characterization by Flenner and Watanabe. For a local ring, you may find the notion of F-rationality useful.

Comment: @Youngsu: thanks ... could you please give a reference for the characterization of Flenner and Watanabe ?

Comment: Hi @user, Flenner, "Rationale quasihomogene Singularitaeten", Arch. Math. Vol. 36, 33-44 (1981) (I believe Satz 3.1 is the one) and Watanabe, "Rational singularities with k∗-action", Commutative algebra (Trento, 1981), pp. 339–351,
Lecture Notes in Pure and Appl. Math.

Comment: As I said, $e(R)$ only sees the initial form of $f$, but rational singularity depends on higher order terms too.